# Incorrect size of the scroll bar in the list view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, scrollbar

Hell all. I work on some desktop application that contains some UI windows created by WPF. One of these windows has a table. Each of the headers in this table can open our custom control for filtering. This custom control contains the ListView element with binding to some collection of items. And when I change the state of some items in this collection the scroll bar in the ListView scrolling incorrectly.

Here is the class that I use to represent the info about each item in the ListView:

```
public class ItemInfo : ViewModelBase
{
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => isSelected;
        set
        {
            Set(ref isSelected, value);
        }
    }

    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get => isAvailable;
        set
        {
            Set(ref isAvailable, value);
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            Set(ref name, value);
        }
    }

    private string name;
    private bool isSelected = true;
    private bool isAvailable = true;
}
```

Each of the items in the ListView contains the checkbox. The **IsSelected** property indicates the state of this checkbox. The **IsAvailable** property indicates if the item in the ListView will be visible or hidden.

Here is the code for the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionForFiltering}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                <CheckBox.Content>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </CheckBox.Content>
            </CheckBox>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The **CollectionForFiltering** is described as:

```
List<ItemInfo> items = new List<ItemInfo>(... some collection of items ...);
ICollectionView CollectionForFiltering = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
```

In some cases, I change the **IsAvailable** property for some items in the collection. And these items will be hidden in the ListView. But when I try to scroll the list I see some changes in the scrollbar size during the scrolling. Please, see the attached gif:

[image: List scrolling]

How can I fix that? How can I refresh/update the scrollbar after some items are hidden?

Comment: Don't hide the visual containers. Remove the actual items from the source collection and add them back as necessary.

Comment: @mm8 but does it mean that I should have one more collection? 1 - to save all items (with any value of **IsAvailable** property) and 2 - to save only the actual items (where **IsAvailable** == true).

Comment: Yes, for example. One collection that contains all items and one that contains the filtered ones that are currently visible in the view.